# Use string in match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Hello i have a script where i have an textarea with the meta description and i have a input text field where i put the keyword. Then i print the matches and i have so far made this script:

```
var countDescription = tinymce.get('myTextEditor').getContent();
var count =  (countDescription.match(/is/g) || []).length;
```

And it works great, but my problem is instead of matching the word "is" i want it to match my string "u"

I have tried something like:

```
var count =  (countDescription.match("/" +u, "/g") || []).length;
```

But it really doesnt work..

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I don't understand what's the reasoning behind your attempt.

Comment: I'm assuming `u` is a variable, hence the duplicate, but you did write the **string** `u`, and if it is just a string, it should be obvious that `countDescription.match(/u/g)` matches a literal `u` ?

Comment: its a string with an word in. Example u could be service, gems, support, about us, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `RecExp` object here:

```
var count = (countDescription.match(new RegExp(u, 'g')) || []).length;
```

Where variable `u` contains the string you want to match.

**PS:** Make sure `u` doesn't have any special regex meta characters. Otherwise you will need to escape them.

Comment: Thanks this works fantastic! So simple, i have been using days on this. Thanks alot!

Comment: Have any idea how i make this so it has to be a word for itself? something like 
var count =  (countDescription.match(new RegExp('\b' + u + '\b', 'g')) || []).length;

Comment: Sorry to respond late, just came back online. It will be: `countDescription.match(new RegExp("\\b" + u + "\\b", 'g'))`

Comment: Works great. Thanks alot. Marked as answered :-)